# How can I insert an entity and it's relationship in REST API?

Tags: rest

I have some problem concerning designing Restful API.
I have these tables:

```
products
    id
    title
    description
    quantity
    price
images
    id
    product_id
    image_path
```

And I need to create a REST API for giving the user ability to do CRUD operations on these two tables.

As you can see the product can have many images. Now in my clients's page for adding a product I need to have a form to add a product and it's related images.
which means by submitting the form, I have to add to both `products` and `images` table.

Now what of the following practices is the correct and the best practice one:

1. having `POST localhsot/api/products/` as an endpoint for adding a product and it's related images.
   flow: sending a request to the endpoint with the json data of product and related images to be added.
2. having `POST localhost/api/products/images` as an endpoint for adding a product and it's related images
   flow: sending a request to the endpoint with the json data of product and related images to be added.

and having `POST localhsot/api/products/` for adding just the product without the image.

3. `POST localhost/api/product` for adding products separately 
   `POST localhost/api/images` for adding images separately.

flow: sending first request for adding product and getting the generated primary key for the product.
then sending the second request with the product's primary key to add and associate the images to the product.

Answer (score 1):

İf the two submissions go hand in hand there is no need to mirror your tables. You can have a single endpoint like submit that handles both.

Comment: Would you care to explain more? Do you mean like the first practice that I have mentioned in the question?